# Como capturar as cores de um Label que está atrás de outro label?

Tags: java, swing, listener

Eu tenho dois JLabels sobrepostos um ao outro.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setBounds(15, 15, 300, 300);
label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(Color.red);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
label1.setBounds(60, 60, 300, 300);
label1.setOpaque(true);
label1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,125));
```

O "`label`" está **`abaixo`** do "`label1`" e ambos estão inseridos em um `GlassPane`:

```
layeredPane.add(label, 0, 0);
layeredPane.add(label1, 1, 0);
```

o GlassPane está perfeito dentro do frame

```
frame.setGlassPane(layeredPane);
layeredPane.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Apenas para o "`label`" (o que está abaixo do "label1") eu criei um evento no mouse e quando eu passar o mouse sobre este label eu quero que ele retorne o valor RGB da sua cor.

```
ml = new MouseMotionAdapter() {public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {

      Point point = evt.getLocationOnScreen();

      Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)point.getX(),(int)point.getY());
      System.out.println(color);
      }

};
```

Como eu não quero que ele traga nenhum retorno do `label1`, eu inclui:

```
 label1.removeMouseMotionListener(ml);
 label.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
```

O código funciona normalmente no que se refere a **área dos labels**. Mas o mouse ainda retorna o RGB das cores do `label1` sobre o `label`, quando de fato eu quero  que o mouse retorne apenas o valor RGB para a cor do "`label`" que está abaixo do "`label1`".

segue o código completo

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;


public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
{
    JFrame frame;
    Robot robot;
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    MouseMotionListener ml;

    robot = new Robot();
    frame = new JFrame("Pc");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
    layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                                "Move the Mouse to Move Duke"));
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setBounds(15, 15, 300, 300);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.red);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setBounds(60, 60, 300, 300);
    label1.setOpaque(true);
    label1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,125));

    layeredPane.add(label, 0, 0);
    layeredPane.add(label1, 1, 0);


    frame.setSize(660, 400);

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    frame.setGlassPane(layeredPane);
    layeredPane.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true); 

       ml = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {

                Point point = evt.getLocationOnScreen();

                Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)point.getX(),(int)point.getY());
                System.out.println(color);
            }
  };        
            label1.removeMouseMotionListener(ml);
            label.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
    }
}
```

Comment: De onde vem esse `robot`?

Comment: Do frame   `public void Frame1() throws AWTException
    {
        robot = new Robot();...}`

Comment: Tem como adicionar um trecho executável desse JFrame com o problema?

Comment: veja se atende!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o que você está resgatando são as coordenadas da tela quando o mouse se move, e não as coordenadas do componente desejado. Por isso é retornado a cor do label que está sobreposto e não do label que está por baixo quando as coordenadas de ambos coincidem.

Pegue as coordenadas do componente ao invés de pegar da tela toda, senão o que vai ser levado em consideração é a cor sobreposta:

```
ml = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {

        JComponent comp = (JComponent) evt.getSource();
        Point point = comp.getLocationOnScreen();

        Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY());
        System.out.println(color);
    }
};

label.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
```

A saída será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que a cor(em RGB) é sempre `255,0,0`, ou seja, [é a cor vermelha](https://www.google.com.br/search?newwindow=1&q=rgb%20%28255%2C0%2C0%29&oq=rgb%20%28255%2C0%2C0%29&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.10466.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0.cb-X4GcxS2c) do `JLabel` que foi sobreposto.

Uma observação: A linha `label1.removeMouseMotionListener(ml);` é desnecessária no código, uma vez que o listener jamais é aplicado ao componente, então não há necessidade de remover.

Comment: Diego, você é o cara!!! Era isso que estava tentando resolver! Como eu sou noob neste site como eu te agradeço! :)

Comment: @vinuales disponha! :) Você pode marcar a resposta como aceita, clicando no `V`, assim, ela servirá de referencia para outros com problema semelhante,