# Como movimentar o objeto para onde eu clicar o mouse?

Tags: java, opengl

Meu problema é o seguinte: tenho um programa em OpenGl com Java.

Fiz uma animação para o desenho se movimentar, aumentar e diminuir de tamanho, até aí tudo bem.

Quando fui criar uma função onde ao clicar do mouse, meu desenho se desloca para onde eu cliquei eu não consegui pois quando clico, o mouse pega a coordenada x e y em relação ao pixel da janela e não em relação a onde cliquei no desenho.

Se eu conseguisse pegar a coordenada certa é só jogar na minha variável global x e y que meu desenho iria se deslocar.

Segue o Código:

```
package teste;

import com.sun.opengl.util.*;
//import lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.*;



/**
 * MouseClique.java <BR>
 * author: Brian Paul (converted to Java by Ron Cemer and Sven Goethel) <P>
 *
 * This version is equal to Brian Paul's version 1.2 1999/10/21
 */
public class MouseClique implements GLEventListener, KeyListener, MouseListener {

    float x=0,y=0,x2,larg,alt;
    float Multi;
    float win;
    float xp1,yp1,xp2,yp2,xp3,yp3, rp,gp,bp; // Ponta Avião
    float LimitPositivoY, LimitNegativoY, LimitPositivoX,LimitNegativoX;
    boolean StatusCima, StatusBaixo,StatusEsquerda,StatusDireita;
    boolean direita = false;  
    boolean esquerda = true;
    boolean cima = false;  
    boolean baixo = false; 
    boolean Inicia = false;


    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL gl;
        GLU glu;
        gl = drawable.getGL();
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES); //Ponta do Aviao
            gl.glColor3f(rp, gp, bp); 
            gl.glVertex2f(x+xp1,y+ yp1);  
            gl.glVertex2f(x+xp2,y+ yp2); 
            gl.glVertex2f(x+xp3,y+ yp3); 
            gl.glColor3f(rp, gp, bp); 
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPointSize(5);
         gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS); //Linhas Janela Esquerda Detalhe
            gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);    
            gl.glVertex2f(0,0);  
            gl.glVertex2f(-1,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(-2,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(-3,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(-4,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(-5,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(1,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(2,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(3,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(4,0);
            gl.glVertex2f(5,0); 
            gl.glVertex2f(0,1);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,2);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,3);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,4);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,5);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,-1);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,-2);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,-3);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,-4);
            gl.glVertex2f(0,-5);
            gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();

        Anima(); 

    }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        //Controle dos eventos de teclado
        System.out.println("Evento do teclado");
    switch(e.getKeyChar()) //Cores
    {
            case 'I': 
            case 'i':
                //Inicia = true;
                break;
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
                //Inicia = false;
                break;
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
            // Ponta Avião
            rp = 0;
            gp = 0;
            bp =0;  

                break;
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                // Ponta Avião
            rp = 1;
            gp = 1;
            bp =1;  


                break;
            case '1':
            if(xp2*1.2f<=LimitPositivoX && yp2*1.2f<=LimitPositivoY && xp3*1.2f>=LimitNegativoX && yp3*1.2f>=LimitNegativoY)
            {
            xp1 = xp1*1.2f;
            yp1 = yp1*1.2f;
            xp2 = xp2*1.2f;
            yp2 = yp2*1.2f;
            xp3 = xp3*1.2f;
            yp3 = yp3*1.2f;

            }
                break;
        }
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) // Posição
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                direita =false;
                esquerda=true;
                cima = false;
                baixo = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                cima = false;
                baixo = false;
                direita = true;
                esquerda =false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                cima = true;
                baixo = false;
                direita = false;
                esquerda =false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                cima = false;
                baixo = true;
                direita = false;
                esquerda =false;
                break;
        } 
    }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  
        System.out.println("Evento do mouse");
        switch (e.getButton()) {
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON1:
                float w, h;
               w=(float)e.getX();
               h=(float)e.getY();
                System.out.println(w+","+h);
               break;
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON3:

               break;
        }
    }  

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable, boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) {
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        GLU glu = new GLU();
        gl.setSwapInterval(1);
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.96f, 0.71f, 0.0f);
        Multi = 8;
        // Ponta Avião
        xp1 = -1f/Multi;
        yp1 = 3f/Multi;
        xp2 = 0f/Multi;
        yp2 = 5.0f/Multi;
        xp3 = 1f/Multi;
        yp3 = 3f/Multi;
        rp = 0;
        gp = 0;
        bp = 0;  
        gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);

       drawable.addKeyListener(this); 
       drawable.addMouseListener(this); 
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        GLU glu = new GLU();
        if (height <= 0) {
            height = 1;
        }
        final float h = (float) width / (float) height;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        glu.gluPerspective(45.0f, h, 1.0, 20.0);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void Anima() {
        if(Inicia){
           if(direita) {
            // Ponta Avião
            xp1 += 0.03f;
            xp2 += 0.03f;
            xp3 += 0.03f;

        }
        if(esquerda) {
            // Ponta Avião
            xp1 -= 0.03f;
            xp2 -= 0.03f;
            xp3 -= 0.03f;


        }
        if(cima){
            // Ponta Avião
            yp1 += 0.03f;
            yp2 += 0.03f;
            yp3 += 0.03f;


        }
        if(baixo){
            // Ponta Avião
            yp1 -= 0.03f;
            yp2 -= 0.03f;
            yp3 -= 0.03f;

        }
        if(yp2>=LimitPositivoY){
            cima = false;
            baixo = true;
            esquerda = false;
            direita = false;
        }
        if(yp3<=LimitNegativoY){
            cima = true;
            baixo = false;
            esquerda = false;
            direita = false;
        }
        if(xp2<=LimitNegativoX) {
            esquerda=false;
            direita=true;
            cima = false;
            baixo = false;
        }
        if(xp3>=LimitPositivoX) {
            esquerda=true;
            direita=false;
            cima = false;
            baixo = false;
        }
        try {
        //    Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Animaç±ao");
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas();
        canvas.addGLEventListener(new MouseClique());
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        final Animator animator = new Animator(canvas);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        animator.stop();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentei captar o x e o y com os comandos: e.getX() e.getY(), mas não estou conseguindo transformar em coordenada OpenGl

Comment: As coordenadas que eu pego por exemplo são: (580,390) mas meu objeto a coordenada esta (4,1).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta e forneça mais informações da sua duvida, e um codigo que seja **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar.

Comment: Movimento de um objeto em tela é uma operação de translação. Estude as funções que fazem isso.

Comment: Transladar eu sei fazer, meu problema é pegar a coordenada do desenho ao clicar o mouse.

Comment: Editei a pergunta como solicitado.

Comment: Não é possivel executar o código, ele não é reproduzivel. Há dependencias não mencionadas.

Comment: Seu problema é solucionado [**nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195522/28595). Da uma lida nela.